# Non-calendar time for pandas time series

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a Python application which will be handling trajectory data. I'm looking at using pandas time series as a way of representing the data (basically a series of positions). The documentation describes all the various ways that one can specify the time information, but there's an assumption that it's tied to calendar dates. What I really want is to represent time as floating point numbers, starting at 0.0. Is this an appropriate use of pandas constructs? If so, is it straightforward to accomplish?

Comment: If you have your time column arranged in order, you can take the first value and subtract it from each row within that column. This will give your the first row as 0 and the rest an increment of it.

Comment: I'm playing with using epoch timestamps. I don't really care if pandas thinks I'm talking about Jan. 1, 1970.

Comment: Would using a timedelta fit your purpose?

Comment: I think the afore-mentioned epoch timestamps are the least cumbersome way of getting pandas time values, but I'm getting the feeling that I'm fighting the tool - that its abstractions don't really fit the problem I'm trying to solve.